# error parsing loadbalancer.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: found character that cannot start any token

Tags: json, azure, yaml, kubectl, azure-aks

I ran this yaml file using kubectl apply -f loadbalancer.yaml command, but got "error parsing loadbalancer.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: found character that cannot start any token" error. Does anyone know why? FYI For indentations, I used spaces not tabs. Thanks ahead!

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
 name: lbservice
spec: 
 type: LoadBalancer
 selector: 
  app: server
 ports: 
 - name: server-port
   port: 3200
   targetPort: 3000
 - name: client-port
   port: 3300
   targetPort: 3001
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: server-pod
    labels:
        app: server
spec:
    containers:
        - name: server-container
          image: tyunlee/infinite:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
nodeSelector:
    disktype: ssd
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: client-pod
    labels:
        app: server
spec:
    containers:
        - name: client-container
          image: tyunlee/infinite:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3001
nodeSelector:
    disktype: ssd
```

Comment: The YAML you posted is valid, and hence the error cannot be reproduced. Please ensure that what you posted is, byte by byte, exactly the YAML you are processing.

Answer (score 1):

A few times ago I faced a similar issue. The solution is that you have to use spaces instead of tabs (exactly two spaces) as YAML does not allow tabs (\t).

See the discussion [here](https://github.com/moraes/config/issues/1), you will get better understanding.